# How to make same server IP accessible from multiple interfaces that are not bridged on Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, ip, routing

My server have two interfaces (e.g. `A`, `B`) that are not bridged. These interfaces have different IP adresses (e.g. `192.168.1.1`, `10.0.0.1`). These IP addresses are in different subnets.

I need to achieve following:
Client connected to the interface `A` (with IP `192.168.1.1`) can access the server using the `10.0.0.1`. (Not vice versa and I cannot just bridge these two interfaces because of additional settings.)

Is it possible to achieve this with Windows Server 2008 R2, if so how?

**Update:** The client which is connected to the interface A has set a default gateway as `192.168.1.1`. (So it should route all IPs from other subnets to the server.)

Comment: Then it should 'just work'. If it doesn't, troubleshoot to figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a windows problem but a networking problem.  if you are on the 192.168.1.x network, you would need a router to get traffic over to the 10.0.0.x network.  If there is no router then you will be unable to connect to any other networks.

Comment: See my update. (The server should be the router. My question is how to setup it correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that either the clients have an appropriate route (10.0.0.1 reachable through 192.168.1.1) or whatever device is their gateway has an appropriate route. There should be nothing special you should have to do -- so long as your routing is sensible, this should "just work".

Comment: Yes, see my update. The clients from `192.168.1.0/24` can also access other clients/subnets that are connected/routable from `10.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is acting as a gateway, has both the 192.168.1.1 and the 10.0.0.1 addresses, and the client is using it as its gateway, then the client you should be able to reach both its "internal" interface (the one the server directly shows to the client) and its "external" one (the one the server has on the other side). No special confgiuration should be required for this.

The client will simply send to the server packets addressed to 10.0.0.1 (because it's its default gateway), and the server will handle them itself because it knows that it owns that address.

You should have routing enabled between the two interfaces, though (just add the RRAS role and configure it as a simple router with no NAT).